# How to check if PHP-FPM is installed and active in PHP

Tags: lamp, php

These are the ones Ive tried but not seeing any PHP-FPM values.

```
print_r(ini_get_all());
print_r(get_defined_constants());
echo php_sapi_name();
print_r(get_loaded_extensions());
```

in phpinfo, I can see php-fpm being installed and the value is active.

Comment: **in phpinfo, I can see php-fpm being installed and the value is active.** um so you don't trust phpinfo?

Comment: This question is old, but I recently ran into something similar so I think it's worth posting here: Remember that you can have 2 configurations for PHP CLI and PHP-FPM, so when you check phpinfo via the CLI version you may not see all extensions your PHP-FPM may have.

Answer (score 4):

Based on @René Höhle's answer, here's my way :

```
ob_start();
phpinfo();
$phpinfo = ob_get_contents();
ob_get_clean();
preg_match('/<tr><td class="e">Server API <\/td><td class="v">(.+)<\/td><\/tr>/', $phpinfo, $phpapi);

if (trim($phpapi[1]) == "FPM/FastCGI" && version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '7.3.0') < 0) {
    echo "Warning, FPM is activated and PHP version is < 7.3.0. Function apache_request_headers is probably not available<br/>";
}
```

other value for $phpapi can be "Apache 2.0 Handler" if the php module is used instead of PHP-FPM

Answer (score 1):

You could use `exec` or `system` and check with `ps aux | grep php-fpm` if its running. The problem is that on some shared hosting system that commands are disabled.

I think normally you can't see, in your phpinfo, if you're running php-fpm because it's a fastcgi implementation.

Another tricky way is to get the content from your phpinfo file and check if the value is insight.

```
ob_start();
phpinfo();
$variable = ob_get_contents();
ob_get_clean();
```

Then you have the content of your phpinfo in your `$variable` and you can check with [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) for example if the part is insight your variable.

Comment: Unfortunately that didnt do the trick. I didn't find the values I was looking for in phpinfo() somehow.